# How can I read rest of bytes after 24 bytes from a NSData variable in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

How to read rest of bytes after 24 bytes from a NSData variable in objective c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `subdataWithRange:` method of `NSData` to get an `NSData` object with the data after the first 24 bytes.

You would do something like:

```
NSData *newData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(24, [data length] - 24)];
```

There is also the `getBytes:range:` method that returns the bytes in a buffer.